# Virtuemart Plugin Errors Elements not defined

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

Is anybody experience this kind of issue before ?

In my joomla 1.7 and VM2.0.6 version of the sites back end payment plugin section
paypal and other the order status area missing select box options like.

```
status_pending  Element not defined for type = vmorderstate
status_success  Element not defined for type = vmorderstate
status_canceled     Element not defined for type = vmorderstate
```

I found some of the links by goggling [link](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=1776583) ,[link](https://forum.virtuemart.net/index.php?topic=89026.0) but unable to solve

Any help or links will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Post here some picture how does the error look. It seems as the problem in vm config, but i need to see this.

Comment: @JTC thanks for your reply i got the solution .actually the elements folder from administartor/com_virtuemart/ is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.

One `elements` folder is missing from `administrator/com_virtuemart/` path.
I checked with original VM2.0.6 version and found my sites lost `elements` folder.

The issue get fixed by uploading that folder to proper path.

thank you..